# ffmpeg dts_delta_threshold and aresample=async=1

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to encode livestreams for use in a tvheadend server. ffmpeg and hls discontinuities dont work, but ive fixed that using streamlink to read the hls stream then pipe that into ffmpeg.

Sometimes the audio has gaps in the live stream and the audio goes out of sync from that point on, I have managed to fix this using aresample=async=1. ffmpeg inserts silence for the gaps and audio stays synced.

Tvheadend doesnt like dts discontinuities and the stream will freeze whenever one is encountered. I have also fixed this with dts_delta_threshold 1. With this option the stream plays seamlessly without any freezes

Here is where my problem comes in when using dts_delta_threshold 1 the aresample command no longer works, I assume because there are no more gaps so it cant insert the silence. Ive tried various combinations and ordering of options.

Is there any way to apply the aresample=async=1 and also the dts_delta_threshold 1 command after.

This is my current command

```
streamlink -l warning --ringbuffer-size 64M --hls-timeout 100000000 --hls-live-restart hls://192.168.10.1/play/$1.$2.m3u8 best -O | \
ffmpeg -loglevel fatal -err_detect ignore_err \
-f mpegts -i - \
-filter_complex "eq=contrast=${3:-1.0}" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" \
-c:a aac -b:a 256k -ac 2 -af aresample=async=1 \
-metadata service_provider=$1 -metadata service_name="$1.$2" -f mpegts pipe:1
```

Ive tried putting the dts_delta_threshold before and after input, same thing audio goes out of sync if there is a gap in audio. Ive tried putting async 1 before input but that doesnt work either

Comment: dts_delta_threshold realigns timestamps when delta between latest packet and last valid packet is greater than the threshold. Not what you want. Don't use that option and instead generate a constant rate output video stream by adding `-vsync cfr`. ffmpeg will dup frames.

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried that vsync cfr but doesnt fix the discontinuities. I think realigning the timestamps is what I want since if there is a big difference in the timestamps I will get a message in tvheadend. "DTS discontinuity. DTS = 552673650, last = 483997170" and the stream will freeze and if there are many it will eventually start playing back slowly and I have to restart the stream.

Comment: dts_delta_threshold fixes this, the stream plays seamlessy and it fixes those errors. The problem is when the audio has a gap in it that it causes it to be out of sync. Thats why I thought if I could apply the dts_delta_threshold after the async command has been performed on the audio it would be fixed, but maybe im thinking about it all wrong.

Comment: dts_delta_threshold takes effect before decoding, so before aresample. The values you quote represent a discont of 10+ minutes. Maybe, skip video encoding, and perform only aresample with -copyts. Pipe result to another ffmpeg where you perform dts_deltra correction and audio copy.

Comment: Ive tried pretty much every possible combination of commands and I just cant keep the video running smoothly and in sync. I tried piping it to a separate ffmpeg where I then run dts command and it still goes out of sync. Is there anyway to make ffmpeg generate completely new timestamps. I tried use_wallclock_as_timestamps and the video just plays at like 2x speed.

Comment: so it seems all I had to do was copy the video instead of encoding and now any ts segments can be in the playlist with completely different resolution or bitrate etc and it has been playing seemlessly so far. Still encoding audio of course with async=1and now it stays synced